# Changing senders, same spam messages

Tags: email, spam

We have a situation at work regarding to our mail filtering appliance and I was hoping that you could give us some insight on how to approach this issue.

We've been receiving spam emails with the subject "Curriculum Vitae (Name)" from different gmail accounts. Even though blocking those individual accounts is simple, we would like to find a workaround so that we don't have to do it manually; blocking any mail with such subject is not convenient, as it wouldn't let legitimate mails come through.

Although we had initially thought of blocking any sender who tries to get several messages delivered briefly (something like a burst of emails), from what we were told by the supplier there is no such functionality in this appliance.

By the way, our mail filtering solution is InterScan Messaging Security Virtual Appliance from Trend Micro.

Any ideas will be truly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you are asking about a specific configuration for a specific program. You will have to work with your vendor's support for that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not speak of your email server/provider. Some allow you admin access to search for and delete/purge emails with certain header info or subject lines (I know I did it in MS Exchange and Google Apps).

But, technology can only take you so far with email protection. If your vendor is offering you all the technical support they can, you need to supplement with triggering your Security Awareness program.